# How to find hotfix version of flutter sdk?

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

I need to know my hotfix version in flutter SDK due to a incompatibility of a dependency with my current SDK's hotfix version. I tried "flutter --version --verbose" and "flutter doctor -v" but it wasn't helpful to show me the version of hotfix.

Comment: i think `v1.12.13+hotfix.9` was the old and last version in hotfix..now version `1.22.4` is latest version ..i think you wont get written  hotfix in latest version...useful link --> https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases

Comment: maybe that's true, but not completely sure about it, I found that was hotfix 9 by looking at my download history ,anyway, thanks!